# Как удалить директорию и все файлы и директории в ней?

Tags: php

Нужно удалить директорию и все вложенные в неё файлы и папки.

Попробовал такую функцию:

```
function removeDirectory($dir) {
if ($objs = glob($dir."/*")) {
   foreach($objs as $obj) {
     is_dir($obj) ? removeDirectory($obj) : unlink($obj);
   }
}
rmdir($dir);}
```

Не работает! Подскажите в чём дело?

Может есть другие соображения по данному вопросу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поробовал не рекурсивно:

```
$directory = escapeshellarg($directory);  exec("rmdir /s /q $directory");
```

Работает!

Answer (score 3):

Классическая функция рекурсивного удаления, пользуйтесь:

```
function rmRec($path) {
  if (is_file($path)) return unlink($path);
  if (is_dir($path)) {
    foreach(scandir($path) as $p) if (($p!='.') && ($p!='..'))
      rmRec($path.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$p);
    return rmdir($path); 
    }
  return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function rm($dir) {
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir),
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST
    );

    foreach ($iterator as $path) {
      if ($path->isDir()) {
         rmdir((string)$path);
      } else {
         unlink((string)$path);
      }
    }
    rmdir($dir);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function removeDir($path) {
    return is_file($path)
    ? @unlink($path)
    : array_map('removeDir',glob('/*')) == @rmdir($path);
}
```

Этот вариант работает? Проверьте права на папки и файлы, если не работает.

Comment: Как изменить права доступа (атрибуты)на локальном сервере?

Comment: Я такой использую)

Comment: cheh1, через chmod

Answer (score 0):

вот создайте файлик `delpaster.php` с таким кодом:

```
function dell_all($str) {
    $opdirbase = opendir($str);
    while ($filebase = readdir($opdirbase)) {
        if (!preg_match('#delpaster.php#', $filebase)) {
            if (is_file($str.'/'.$filebase)){
                unlink($str.'/'.$filebase);
            } else {
                if (!rmdir($str.'/'.$filebase)) {
                    dell_all($str.'/'.$filebase);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
dell_all($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_files_callback($dir,callable $callback){
    if(is_dir($dir) && is_readable($dir)){
        foreach(scandir($dir) as $val){
            if($val == '.' || $val == '..'){ continue; }
            if(!get_files_callback("{$dir}/{$val}",$callback)){
                call_user_func($callback,"{$dir}/{$val}");
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Для вызова:

```
get_files_callback("/var/www/mysite.com",function($file_or_dir){
    if(is_dir($file_or_dir)){
        return rmdir($file_or_dir);
    }
    return unlink($file_or_dir);
});
```